# Grafana custom time range for one panel only

Tags: grafana

I want to slide the panel graph for 5minute into the future, I know I can do this
using  'Custom Range' at the top right of the screen and setting to 'to' field to 'now+5m' .

[image]

However this will be applied to all my panels.

Now..I want this for only a specific panel.
What I have found is time range tab but it only allows to truncate the time but cant push forward it.
[image]

Is there a way to use this only for one panel?

Comment: Where have you found this "Time Range" tab? When I go to "Add Panel", "Add Query" and insert my query, I then want to customize the time range for the given panel, but I don't see the second image, you have posted. I can define the queries, visualization, general and alert, but none show any Time range in them. I therefore can't find the "Time range" possibility - do you know if it's changed place or somehow isn't available anymore in the newer graf. versions?

Comment: Haven't used it since then, sorry. Maybe try this : https://community.grafana.com/t/time-range-missing/17718/10

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found a solution using addition: `0m+5m`

Seems grafana doesnt substracts the value of the amount field from the current time as a whole 
like `timeshift-(Xm+Ym)`  
 but performs the operations after each other 
like `timeshift-Xm+Ym`

Could be a bug tbh.